# How to create a HTTPS tunnel on my vps for my twitch bot event listen

Tags: node.js, post, vps, twitch

I found an example on how to use the twitch EventSub webhooks(https://github.com/twitchdev/eventsub-webhooks-node-sample/blob/main/index.js) but i'm struggling with finding out how to setup it up without having to install ngrok or other apps on my PC since i have a vps where i host the bot. I understood the GET method but POST is a bit difficult for me.

Hope i explained it well enough for someone to understand.

Comment: You mentioned creating an "HTTPS tunnel" in your question title, but it's not clear exactly how this fits in after reading your question's body. Can you edit it to elaborate on this a bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitch EventSub at time of writing only offers a "Webhook transport"

So you should be able to set this up no problem on your VPS, since your VPS is web accessabile.

To test this locally on your PC yes you will need a proxy/tunnel such as NGROK to make your PC web accessable.

A "webhook transport" (to over simplfy) operates in the same way a login from on a Website does. You fill in the form and hit submit, and the form is POST'ed to the server.

Webhook's it's the same thing, except the data isn't POST'ed as a form but a JSON blob in the body.

So you can use anything capable of receiving a HTTP POST. There are just a few NodeJS examples like the one you have linked kicking about.

TLDR: unless you are testing, skip setting it up on your PC and start with setting it up on your VPS, as the VPS doesn't *need* a tunnel, apache/nginx are the SSL Terminator that passes to your Node script, *if* you use a node script link the linked exmaple in the OP